# Laravel Eloquent, how to handle UNIQUE error?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a MySQL constraint to ensure unique on a composite key. When inserting a new  record in my model `Foo` I get the expected error:

```
$foo = new Foo(['foo' => 42, 'bar => 1]);
$foo->save();
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '42' for key 'Unique'...

One solution to avoid this error is to query the model before inserting:

```
if (!Foo::where('foo', 42)->where('bar', 1)->first()) {
  $foo = new Foo(['foo' => 42, 'bar => 1]);
  $foo->save();
}
```

Another one would be to catch the exception when `preg_match(/UNIQUE/, $e->message)` is `true`.

Is there any better solution?

**EDIT**

I noticed that in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` Laravel does the double query anyway which is a bit sad:

```
public function findOrNew($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    if (! is_null($model = $this->find($id, $columns))) {
        return $model;
    }

    return $this->newModelInstance();
}
```

Comment: Why not update your migration files to remove the constraint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the general case you should be dealing with database errors using the error code and not any regex.

In your particular case pre-querying or using a Laravel method that does that automatically for you, might be preferable if your intention is to overwrite/update existing data.

If you want to generally anticipate an error and handle it you should do something like:

```php
try {
   $foo = new Foo(['foo' => 42, 'bar' => 1]);
   $foo->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) { // It's actually a QueryException but this works too
   if ($e->getCode() == 23000) {
       // Deal with duplicate key error  
   }
}
```

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-reference.html for an exhaustive list of error codes (but ideally you'd only need to deal with a couple of specific errors and under very specific circumstances.

Lastly the SQL `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` might also work for you, however if you are doing this to silently ignore the new values then I suggest you do the error handling instead.

Comment: How can I rethrow the exception if it does not match `$e->code == 23000`?

Comment: `throw $e` from the catch block does a rethrow

Comment: It seems `code` is a protected property: `Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Database\QueryException::$code`

Comment: @nowox sorry. Missed that. Meant to write `getCode()` instead of `code` . Fixed now

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `firstOrCreate` method:

```
$foo = Foo::firstOrCreate(['foo' => 42, 'bar' => 1]);
```

This will check if the record exists in the database before creating it. If it exists, it will return the record.

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Comment: How can I check if it inserted a new entry of if it just got an existing entry?

Comment: @nowox You can use `$foo->wasRecentlyCreated` to check if it's been created or not.

Comment: This goes beyond my question, but how can I do `$foo->baz()->associate($baz)` along with `firstOrCreate`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @nowox.

Comment: Imagine I have a `belongsTo` relationship on one column. To associate a model to this column I usually need two line of code: 1: `$foo = new Foo()`, 2: `$foo->baz()->associate($baz)`. With the use of `firstOrCreate`, I cannot call the `associate` method.

Comment: @nowox Why not? You still have your `$foo` variable. You can still do `$foo->baz()->associate($baz);` like you used to do before? The `firstOrCreate` still returns a `App\Foo` instance just like when you do `new Foo`.

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention that my `baz` is part of my `UNIQUE` index

Comment: @nowox I think you'd have to make a new question with the necessary (Model, Migration) information for us to understand properly. I'd also recommend to fix your database structure instead if it's not supposed to have an unique index in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

laravel provides you with the firstOrCreate functions, which first checks if that value exist in the database, then you also have updateOrCreate function to use incase you want to update some value, but most important one, if you want to handle only unique records then check the validation rules, you would do a FormRequest and add unique rule to that field, after that laravel with provide you with error messages, so you handle the error on the client side

Answer (score 2):

The verification need to be done at Controller level (like laravel Validator) and it's better to do a `count()` instead of the `first()`.

There are different solution depending on what you wanna do when the entity exists in the database. For example you can do `updateOrCreate()`

```
$foo = App\Foo::updateOrCreate(['foo' => 42, 'bar' => 1]);
```

or throw an exception